# A question about affine spaces

Tags: analytic-geometry

Are there affine spaces that contain subsets that aren't closed to affine combinations of three points?

This is a surprising question.

I think that exists that kind of affine spaces,but I don't know what space should be considered as an example.

Please,could you help me?

Comment: Please,could anyone who has the slightest idea about this question answer me?

Comment: What is your definition of an affine space? And of an affine combination?

Comment: An affine space A of direction the vectorial space V is a set of points for which exists a function u:A->V which has the properties:

Comment: 1.u(A,B)+u(B,C)=u(A,C);for each A,B,C from A

Comment: 2.exists O from A such that u(O,A) is a bijection

Comment: An affine combination is a linear combination of points A=a1*A1+...+an*An,which has a1+...+an=1.

Comment: Can we assume that the space is closed under affine combinations of two points?

Comment: No,the subset isn't said to be closed under affine combinations of two points.

Comment: Your function $u$ is a function of one variable, since it is a map from $A$ into the vector space $V.$ It isn't clear what is meant by "for each A,B,C from A," since the overall set A is one of the terms of the list A,B,C. Should different letters like $a,b,c \in A$ be used? Another question, what does $u(a,b)$ mean, since $u$ is a function of one variable?

Comment: u:AxA->V and yes,we must use different notations like a,b and c from A

Comment: coffeemath,could you answer me?

Comment: Adrian-- I have tried to give an answer below, let me know if it fits what you are going for. I still am a bit vague about the assumptions, for example is the "bijection" supposed to preserve scalar multiplications, or at least be continuous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple affine space would be the (x,y) plane, where we use the vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$ as the vector space $V$ of the definition. For two points $a,b$ in the (x,y) plane we can define $u(a,b)=b-a,$ for example $u((1,2),(2,5))=(2,5)-(1,2)=(1,3).$ The origin $(0,0)$ of the (x,y) plane can then be the point $O$ of the second part of the definition, since under the mapping $u$ a random point $a=(x,y)$ of the plane maps to $u((0,0),(x,y))=(x,y)$ which shows this maps the (x,y) plane as an affine space by a bijection to the vector space $V=\mathbb{R}^2.$

Now for a subset $B$ which is not closed under affine combinations, take the three-element set consisting of the vertices $P,Q,R$ of a nondegenerate triangle. Then the affine combination $(1/3)P+(1/3)Q+(1/3)R$ is the centroid of the triangle, and is *not* one of the vertices, so is not in $B.$